# python asyncio In this case, do I have to write 'await' in all the codes? Is there any more effective way?

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio

There is a class about keyboard input and waits a few seconds after typing the key as follows:

```
class Keyboard:
    async def sendpacket(self, keyvalue, s):
        print(f"keyboard write{keyvalue}")
        await asyncio.sleep(s)


key = Keyboard()

async def caseA():
    if random.randint(0,5) == 1:
        await key.sendpacket('a', 0.4)
        await key.sendpacket('o', 0.8)
    else:
        await key.sendpacket('b', 1)
        await key.sendpacket('b', 0.5)
        await key.sendpacket('b', 0.5)

    await key.sendpacket('5', 0.1)
    await key.sendpacket('y', 0.1)
    await key.sendpacket('e', 0.1)
    await key.sendpacket('i', 0.1)
    await key.sendpacket('a', 0.2)

    for i in range(5):
        await key.sendpacket('f', 0.5)
        await key.sendpacket('1', 0.5)
        await key.sendpacket('2', 0.5)

    await key.sendpacket('e', 0.5)
    await key.sendpacket('i', 1)
    await key.sendpacket('a', 2)
            .
            .
            .


async def caseB():
    while True:
        x = random.randint(1, 5)
        print(x)
        await asyncio.sleep(x)

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(caseA(),caseB()))
```

When the key function is very many like caseA,
Should I continue to write the words 'await' for all functions?
Is there a way to omit or a better way?

Comment: If your function is waiting an asynchronous response, then you'll need to await it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to omit the `await`. In this example you can obviously compress them using a `for` loop, but you have to write `await` before functions that return awaitables, such as async functions.